# How can you disable snapshotting on a running Redis for certain DBs?

Tags: redis

How to disable Save for some DBs and allow for the others in the Redis

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. An RDB snapshot is a single file that contains the data of all dbs.
You can send a `FLUSHDB` on the dbs you do not want to restore after the RDB is loaded.

If you'll use a dedicated Redis process for each db you could configure each one differently with a dedicated redis.conf file, and a `SAVE` and `BGSAVE` commands will only create a snapshot of the Redis process it was issued on.

Comment: ok , But in this config file there is IF statement in the save area which may help in this case but i didn't tested it    
https://github.com/arioch/puppet-redis/blob/master/templates/redis.conf.erb

the if is here :
<% if @save_db_to_disk %>
<%- @save_db_to_disk_interval.sort_by{}.each do |seconds, key_change| -%>
save <%= seconds -%> <%= key_change -%> <%= "\n" -%>
<%- end -%>
<% end %>